# error while I am data:{} at nuxt js is it solvable?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, eslint

this is the template I want to make a password input and checkbox while box is checked I want to type inside input to turn into the text instead of password

```html
<!--template-->
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="login">
            <h1 style="font-size:30px; color:black;">Login</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username...">
        <input :type="inputtype" placeholder="Password...">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" :checked="totext">
        <button class="button is-link">Submit</button>
        <a href="">Register</a>
        <a href="" class="repeat">Forgot the password..?!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
  17:5   error    Unexpected labeled statement                                                      no-labels
```

17:16  error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```html
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    inputtype: 'password'
  },
  methods: {
    totext () {
      this.inputtype = this.inputtype === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code instead:

:type="totext ? 'password': 'text' "

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="login">
            <h1 style="font-size:30px; color:black;">Login</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username...">
        <input :type="totext ? 'password': 'text' " placeholder="Password...">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" :checked="totext">
        <button class="button is-link">Submit</button>
        <a href="">Register</a>
        <a href="" class="repeat">Forgot the password..?!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this script:

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      totext : false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Or** this one (the better one)

```
   <template>
        <div>
            <div id="login">
                <h1 style="font-size:30px; color:black;">Login</h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username...">
            <input :type="isText" placeholder="Password...">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" :checked="totext">
            <button class="button is-link">Submit</button>
            <a href="">Register</a>
            <a href="" class="repeat">Forgot the password..?!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

And

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      totext : false
    }
  },
  computed: { 
      isText(){
         return totext ? 'password': 'text'
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
 data: () => ({
inputtype: 'password'
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've merged the two sets of braces.

This:

```js
data () {
  inputtype: 'password'
},
```

should be this:

```js
data () {
  return {
    inputtype: 'password'
  }
},
```

Comment: when I do that this error appears  error  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'return'

Comment: @AbdallahHamouda I don't see any obvious reason why the code I posted would cause that error. Where are you seeing the error?